# prevent mouse middle button to open new tab in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Challenge: prevent mouse middle button to open new tab in anchor tag with a particular class.

my problem is I have tried but it stopped working of all anchor tags in page but I don't want it.I want to stop working of middle button to open a new tab in anchor tab having class name tab1.

visit:  http://jsbin.com/wemapehadu/edit?html,output

can anybody have solution for that...

Comment: Why not post the code you have so far? If it is Javascript all that needs to be added is a class test.

Comment: i send you a link of code          https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=8Ko6K3i1yw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple solution
    
    
    
    
    
    $(function(){
      $(document).on("click", function(e){
        if($(e.target).is("#google") && e.button===1)
          e.preventDefault()
      })
    })
    
    
    JS Bin
    
    
    Google
 Bing

```
[FIDDLE LINK][]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kezcrxop/1/

Answer (score 1):

In your jsfiddle you forgot to enable JQuery, so it could never work.

Your Javascript didn't quite work, but you were going in the right direction. This will work (with JQuery enabled):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("mousedown","a.aa",function(e) {
     if(e.which == 2) {
        e.preventDefault();
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: it's not working. anchor tag open new tab on middle mouse click

Comment: In that case you can remove the 'href' from the link and style class 'aa' so that it looks like a link. Show, me a new jsfiddle if it still doesn't work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#run&togetherjs=8Ko6K3i1yw    but i want a link which should work on left click

Comment: That's possible, I cannot make JSFiddle to work, so look here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyjNyb